# Module imports with and without setuptools build

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I want to make my python app distributable but when I run it from command line from project folder all works well. After the packaging, there is a problem with module import.

All modules exists in package `tlen`. In my app I use eg. `from Sender import Sender` where Sender is `tlen/Sender.py` module.

All works well when I running `tlen/main.py`.

Problem exists when I try do package by `sudo python setup.py install` and run command `tlen`. Then I receive:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tlen-1.0-py3.7.egg/tlen/main.py", line 3, in <module>ModuleNotFoundError: Nomodule named 'Sender'
```

Whole project:
https://github.com/tloszabno/tl_en

My setup.py file:

```
setuptools.setup(
name='tlen',
version='1.0',
author='Tomasz Łoś',
author_email='tloszabno@gmail.com',
description='A tool to learn foreign language',
packages=["tlen"],
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'tlen = tlen.main:main'
    ]
},
classifiers=[
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
    'Operating System :: OS Independent',
],
)
```

What I doing wrong with `import`s?

Comment: Have you tried `from .Sender import Sender`? Note the `.`.

Comment: yes I've tries, but then 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.Sender'; '__main__' is not a package`

Comment: use correct names for absolute imports: `from tlen.Sender import Sender` if you want to run the `main` module via `python tlen/main.py`.

Comment: That works untill I remove tlen from site-packages - thats not what I want.

After removal:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tlen'

Comment: @TomekŁoś What do you mean by "remove `tlen` from site-packages`? That is the package you are about to install. The suggestion by @hoefling is the way to go, use absolute imports.

Comment: The package is not found because you're running `main.py` from the `tlen` directory. In that case you need to adjust the `sys.path` explicitly. `cd tlen; PYTHONPATH=.. python main.py` will work.

Comment: @hoefling from tlen dir same issue:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tlen.Sender import Sender
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tlen'

Comment: @a_guest  `pip uninstall tlen`
"That is the package you are about to install." - please notice that I'm also developing it, and in aproach that you suggest when I provide changes in Sender I need to install it to site-packages, then run main.py to see changes - thats a little pain-in-the-ass

Comment: @hoefling I've tried with PYTHONPATH also fail:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tlen'`

Comment: @tlos First of all, `cd /tmp; git clone https://github.com/tloszabno/tl_en; cd tl_en/tlen; sed -i 's/from Sender/from tlen.Sender/g' main.py; PYTHONPATH=.. python main.py` and voila, `Sender` is importable. Second, you shouldn't run `main.py` at all - if you offer `tlen` command line interface, you should install the package in editable mode while developing (`pip install --editable tl_en`) and run `tlen` as the user of your package will do it. Third, I see gaps in understanding of Python's import system - maybe it's wise to revisit the basics first.

Comment: Instead, you are starting to introduce workarounds that don't solve the initial problem of wrong imports by adding unnecessary modules that are even packaged into the distribution, shadowing the `tlen` interface - this is not a solution by any means.

Answer (score 0):

Hah I've solved it!

Just added app.py file to main dir (.. of tlen) with content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from tlen import main as app
def main():
    app.main()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

then setup.py:

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
name='tlen',
version='1.0',
author='Tomasz Łoś',
author_email='tloszabno@gmail.com',
description='A tool to learn foreign language',
packages=["tlen"],
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'tlen = app:main'
    ]
},
classifiers=[
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
    'Operating System :: OS Independent',
],
scripts=[
        'app.py',
       ]
```

)

Comment: That's no solution, it's a weird workaround. And it will break when distributing the package via pypi for example. The entry point should be distributed as part of the package and it should use absolute imports. See the comments of @hoefling at the OP. They pretty much nail it.